# Plugging household device into T-Blade extension cord does not work

Tags: electrical, extension-cord

I have a 50Amp to 15/20Amp T-Blade extension cord. Here is the [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SJESLMI).

The 50Amp end is plugged into an unused Stove outlet.

When I plug in a surge protector the extension cord does not seem to work. The 3-prong surge protector does not have a T-blade connector. I also tried plugging in 2-prong fan, but this doesn't work either.  No household device that I tried works.

If I use a Voltmeter I see 118VAC at the end of the extension cord. When I plug in the surge protector the protected and grounded lights both turn off. These lights are normally on when plugged into a standard wall outlet.  However, I see 118VAC when I plug the voltmeter into the surge protector outlets.

Am I wrong to expect to be able to plug in household devices to this extension cord?

Does the device need to have a T-blade connector?

UPDATE:
The measured voltage between the 50A socket ground and a nearby 15A socket ground is 0.01V.

@brhans is right. When I measure between the T and the straight it is 105V (nothing plugged in) and changes to 240V (w/ fan plugged in).

I am assuming that he is also correct that a neutral line is missing.

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Plug something simple like a bedside lamp into one side of your T-Blade and turn it on. If it doesn't light up, leave it plugged in and turned on and measure the voltage at the other side of the T-Blade. $10 says you'll see around 240V ...

Comment: Is the 50A stove outlet actually grounded?  Or did they slap a NEMA 14-50 where a NEMA 10-50 once was, and call it "good"?

Comment: Wow, $95 and all the code violation you could ever ask for. I don't see any mention of 20A circuit breakers on this thing, so it's putting 50A into receptacles that should never have more than 20A feeding them. Not a fan...

Comment: @brhans With nothing plugged in I see 12VAC on the T-prong and 118VAC on the straight prong.  When I plug the fan and leave it in the ON state I see 121VAC on both the T-prong and the straight prong.

Comment: It sounds like the 50 amp receptacle is mis-wired. Double check the wiring on the 50 amp receptacle and verify all voltages on that end first.

Comment: I meant you should measure between the T and the straight, not from ground to each one. I think you have a missing neutral at your outlet, and plugging the lamp on one side will then highlight this by giving you (L1 + L2) = 240V on the other side.

Comment: @brhans You are right. When I measure between the T and the straight it is 105V (nothing plugged in) and 240V (w/ fan plugged in).

Comment: I agree with ecrnewal on this what a disaster waiting to happen. 20 amp outlet protected by a 50 amp breaker I can not believe this could be listed.